# How Should I Extend This Wiring For a Ceiling Light?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, junction-box, retrofit, splicing

I’m working on replacing a wall light fixture with one in the center ceiling.  There is no wiring in the ceiling. It’s an old building and there is another floor above this with no space above the rafters.

The wiring coming from the wall is too short (there is no slack) and it is also not central to the room, so I need to both install a junction box to extend it and run a track to the center of the ceiling where the light will be.

This is someone else’s home and they do not want the ceiling or walls torn up, hence the reason I am not replacing the wiring or running it through the ceiling (it might work, but I’m not sure how to get by the the rafters or keep the ceiling intact). I will of course have to make a hole for the fixture’s junction box.

It will operate on a wall switch and I will probably add a pull string to the fixture for extra control because two wall lights operate off the same switch.

What would be the least unsightly and safest way to do this? A junction box on the ceiling for splicing would be kind obvious, but that is where the wires would meet. Any assistance is appreciated. [image]

Comment: That type of ceiling should have three levels, the tiles, 1x3 furring strips, and the ceiling joists.  Make a hole in ceiling for box for light and should be able to run wire back to switch.

Comment: Ah, you are probably right about that. I would still have to install a separate junction box at another point in the ceiling for the splice I guess, unless you are suggesting running a whole new wire. But perhaps if it is flush with the ceiling it wouldn’t look horrible. It just has to be accessible I know.

Comment: The cleanest visually and most professional way to run it is to replace the line all the way back to the switch as suggested by @crip659. It shouldn't be too hard if the ceiling joists are running toward the wall with the switch. If you do a jbox the simplest way would be to place it in the wall where the wire is coming out. If you don't run it through the ceiling your best bet for a surface mount might be wiremold. Personally, I would prefer patching a few drywall holes over seeing wiremold running across the ceiling.

Comment: So that wall is what I suspect is asbestos cement. It’s dark grey and crumbles easily. So I’d rather not mess with that if I don’t have to. Otherwise I guess it wouldn’t be a big deal to patch some holes. The kitchen already has wiremold for a fan, But that is not such a far distance. So I think what I’ll do is try to run it through the ceiling and add a jbox to that wall as close to the ceiling as possible. Not exactly ideal, but it would be the least intrusive option maybe. Or can a wiremold corner bracket be used as a jbox?

Comment: Is surface raceway an option here?

Comment: Wiremold has a shallow junction box.

Comment: I have raceway I purchased for this job. Will it hold up long term to acoustic ceiling tiles? I also will need a special piece for where the wire comes out of the wall.

Comment: The kitchen fan has a junction box designed to meet up with the wiremold. I could probably paint it to blend in. So something like thatbis certainly an option if access to the ceiling doesn’t work out. Right now I’m just trying to figure out where the joists are before I do any cutting. My stud finder isn’t being super helpful.